# Put all 1s of matrix in column 1, 2s in column 2 etc. and NaNs in empty cells

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I want to put all 1's in column 1, all 2's in column 2 etc. of a matrix A. All NaNs should just be placed in the remaining empty cells.

For example,

```
A =  [1 2 3; 1 2 NaN; 1 3 NaN; 2 3 NaN; 2 NaN NaN; 3 NaN NaN; NaN NaN NaN]
A =

     1     2     3
     1     2   NaN
     1     3   NaN
     2     3   NaN
     2   NaN   NaN
     3   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

And I would like to get

```
 B =

     1     2     3
     1     2   NaN
     1   NaN     3
   NaN     2     3
   NaN     2   NaN
   NaN   NaN     3
   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

EDIT: in the general case I have more numbers {1,2,...,N} and then NaN and need to be able to do the exercise for an arbitrary number of distinct numbers.

Comment: @AnderBiguri `A` was repeated in the question, the second time, I believe, just to show it displayed. The question is: have `A`, how to get `B`?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should do what you are trying to achieve:

```
%% Initialise
A    = [1 2 3; 1 2 NaN; 1 3 NaN; 2 3 NaN; 2 NaN NaN; 3 NaN NaN; NaN NaN NaN];
minA = min(min(A));
maxA = max(max(A));


%% For-loop example
B = NaN(size(A, 1), maxA);

for i=1:size(B, 2)
    log_i       = sum(A==i, 2)==1;
    B(log_i, i) = i;
end


%% Vectorized form example
index   = minA:maxA; 
index3D = reshape(index, 1, 1, maxA);

% 3D logical
check = bsxfun(@eq, repmat(A, 1, 1, maxA), index3D);

% Set C
C         = bsxfun(@times, double(check), index3D);
C         = squeeze(sum(C, 2));
C(C<minA) = NaN; % apply NaNs
```

Comment: No worries, I have just updated the code to make it a bit better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This works perfectly with the numbers 1,2,3, but can it be made general so I can use it if I have numers 1,2,3,...,N instead of only 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: It is already, but since you want to have one column per number you should set A correctly (meaning k x n column). Otherwise, you can edit B and the for-loop: B = NaN(size(A, 1), max(max(A))) and for i=1:size(B, 2). I haven't tried this code on Matlab, but it should work.

Comment: Is it possible to do in a vectorized form?

Comment: That is awesome! `repmat` in 3D and this `squeeze` trick... I spend a hour trying to do the same! Good answer!

Comment: Good answer. You showed 4 different techniques... and suffice to say that you removed all of my options to provide another answer :-).